# How to delay RxJava Subscription on both Success and Error?

Tags: android, rx-java2

I would like to delay the subscription to dispatch by XXXX time regardless of error or success. With the following code the delay is working for the success scenario only. Please help me so that it can wait XXXX time always.

```
serviceRepository.getService()
                           .retry(0)
                           .map(value -> {
                               total = XXXX;
                               return value;
                           })
                           .observeOn(schedulerProvider.mainThread())
                           .delaySubscription(total, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                           .subscribeWith(return new DisposableSingleObserver<ServiceResponse>() {

                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(ServiceResponse serviceResponse) {


                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Throwable e) {

                   }
               });
```

Comment: Delaying subscription by time will never fail on its own. I'm not sure what you try to achieve here. Also `retry(0)` won't ever retry.

Comment: If there's an Exception then map's callback won't be triggered.

Comment: Anatolii What's the alternative If I would like to delay both success and error regardless. XXXX is dynamic so I need to have something equivalent  to map

Answer (score 1):

Move the `delaySubscription` before the `retry` call. RxJava operators operate upwards, so your delay applies to the original subscription to the retry, but not the additional subscription in the error case, since retry only knows what exists upstream.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But noticed map wont be called on error but I would like to call map as I XXX is dynamic I calculate based on how long the network call takes .If the network call takes longer the value of XXXX will be much shorter